# How to enable occulusion culling in Ogre3D?

Tags: ogre, ogre3d

In my scene, there are 30.000 cubes and even the invisible ones are being rendered by default and that affects fps in a bad way.

I don't want to implement it from scratch, and I suspect there must be an implemented occlusion culling for Ogre3D. Do you know how to enable the default occulusion culling system in Ogre?

Answer (score 0):

There is no out of the box solution for occlusion culling in Ogre, but it has been an active topic in the forums, and it is in the current [roadmap](http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/tiki-index.php?page=TindalosNotes) for Ogre 2.0.

Using the PCZ Scenemanager with various portals may get you some of the desired functionality, depending on your scene.

Searching the ogre forums for Coherent Hierarchical Culling (CHC) may get you some potential starting points, such as the [work by Tuan Kuranes](http://www.ogre3d.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=38383).